# How do I define an extension for coffeeify with Budo dev server?

Tags: coffeescript, browserify

I'm trying to use coffeeify with budo so I do not have to add the extension to my require statements. I have tried passing these commands through budo's browserify options

> budo src/app.coffee --live --serve bundle.js -- -t coffeeify --extension=".coffee"
>
> budo src/app.coffee --live --serve bundle.js -- -t [coffeeify --extension=".coffee"]

I also tried inserting the browserify transform into my package.json

> "browserify: {
> "transform": ["coffeeify", {"extension": ".coffee"}]
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works for me (took me forever to figure it out, the hard part being getting watchify to work with coffeescript). *Everything* is in the package.yaml. Invoke `npm start` from your top folder and it will do the trick. npm puts all the locally installed node binaries in your PATH for you (they normally live under `node_modules/.bin`).

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "(cd src; budo app.coffee:bundle.js --dir . --live --verbose -- --extension=.coffee | garnish)"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "extension": [ ".coffee" ],
    "transform": [ ["coffeeify"], ["brfs"] ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "brfs": "1.4.1",
    "browserify": "11.1.0",
    "budo": "^5.1.5",
    "coffee-script": "latest",
    "coffeeify": "^1.1.0",
    "garnish": "^3.2.1",
    "watchify": "3.4.0"
  }
}
```

I have my source code under the src folder, and a file named app.coffee which includes (or `require` in node.js terms) my whole application. I have an index.html in my src folder which reference the bundle.js through from an html `script` tag.

1. The command to start budo is inside my package.json. It does cd into my src folder first.
2. The trick is to specify some configuration in the browserify block: the extension .coffee needs to be present, and a list of transforms as well. I tried to have everything on the command line but never got it to work
3. After `npm start` is invoked, since I pass the `--live` argument to `budo` everything works like magic and edit/saves to my documents do trigger a browser reload/refresh.

To deploy or release you'll probably need another target to minify with uglify.js. I still have a script that does that manually in 2 steps, the first step calls browserify and the second step calls uglify.js explicitely.

As a remark, recent version of budo do the piping into garnish for you I've heard.
Another tip is to look at what the React folks are doing to transform their .jsx files, as it is in theory extremely close to what the coffeescript folks need to do. There seems to be a huge momentum around React so hopefully React people will have figured those build problems first.

Comment: @Navx, do you mind adding the budo tag to your post to improve the categorization ?